# MacBook Air screen is dim

Tags: display, macbook-air

I have a MacBook Air 2014, and the screen is really badly dim- almost nothing is visible; only thing I can hardly see is the apple logo at startup.

I have changed the display panel with the screen itself hoping its a bad display, but this didn't solve the problem.

The connector of the screen cable looks a bit rusted. I tried to clean it with a tooth brush and alcohol but no difference.

Could it be a bad board?

Comment: just to check the obvious......is the brightness all the way up?

Comment: yes it was a faulty board changing that solved the problem